# How to validate Class properties correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm working on a web application, trying to validate properties like:

```
public int Code
{
    get { return _Code; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("El código debe ser mayor que 0!");                    
        }
        _Code = value;
    }
}
```

or a validate method:

```
private bool ValidateCode(int code)
{
    bool range = false;

    if (code >= 1)
    {
        range = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Code out of range...");
    }

    return range;
}
```

The issue with these two, is on the first one, the flow is cut and the program falls into an unhandled exception. I just found, exceptions are not for validations, so I decided to use the second choice and, after detect the error, even with it, the flow goes on.

I need to validate the variable and if the conditions doesn't match, send a message without cut the flow out, and then go on as normal, all that in business layer.

Comment: I would prefer first if there is certain condition to meet to set the value. For e.g. :  if you have Age property in your business class , then it should be greater than 0. If not, there should be ArgumentException which should clearly define, what causes an error.  If there is something coming from view, then you can validate incoming input in your method. For eg. if there is email coming from view, then you can validate email in your method.

Comment: There is a method with those conditions and handler, but, it fails at runtime. Need to send a message without ends program's flow, like: "You entered a wrong value, please do it again"... "Value accepted"...

Comment: As I assume your `Code` property in business layer type and I believe, your business layer should always be valid and it should not accept value which does not meet the contract offered by business layer type. It's consumer(your view side handler in your case) responsibility to handle any exception thrown from business layer incase of invalid data.

Comment: Got it. I'll give it a try. Thank You!!!